# Losing $_POST data after a submitted multipart/form-data form reload(Firefox)

Tags: php, forms, firefox, post, php-7.1

Losing `$_POST` data after a submitted multipart/form-data form reload.

I have the below form:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST, $_FILES); ?>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name1" value="name1"/>
    <input type="text" name="name2" value="name2"/>
    <input type="file" name="file" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="name3" value="name3"/>
    <input type="text" name="name4" value="name4"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The issue is that when i submit this form with a file selected (maybe 2b - 3kb) for the first time i get

```
'name1' => string 'name1' (length=5)
'name2' => string 'name2' (length=5)
'name3' => string 'name3' (length=5)
'name4' => string 'name4' (length=5)

'file' => array (size=5) [...]
```

But then when I hit the reload button I get this:

```
array (size=2)
'name1' => string 'name1' (length=5)
'name2' => string 'name2' (length=5)

'file' => array (size=5) [...]
```

More like all the data that came after `file` is lost.
I tried not selecting any file, submitted the form and reloaded it and didnt lose any data from the `$_POST`.
And also when i move `name3` and `name4` above `file` their data remains after reload.
I need help.

Made demo here: https://vimeo.com/272339637

Comment: I have copied your code and tried myself. That is not happening for me. Everything remains after refresh.

Comment: i tried it here also https://ide.c9.io/chrys_u/stack

Comment: So now what your `var_dump` gone crazy again as you commented previously and deleted your question.

Comment: Lol yes. I dont know, is it possible for a browser to cause this issue?

Comment: i notice it happens on firefox alone.

Comment: Is that all of your code what you have shown above? Because in my firefox too it works. Everything remains after refresh. Does it asks for confirmation to refresh saying it will send the previously sent data again?

Comment: yes. it does but shows only the 1st 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i contacted Firefox support, I seem to be a known issue with Firefox  > v60.0 Forms. [Firefox form Issues](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1219615) So my best option for now was to move all `text` above `file`. Eg:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name1" value="name1"/>
    <input type="text" name="name2" value="name2"/>
    <input type="text" name="name3" value="name3"/>
    <input type="text" name="name4" value="name4"/>

    <input type="file" name="file" value=""/>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```